# JavaScript and VBScript Code Comparison

Tags: javascript, vbscript

What is the JS replacement for the below VB code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "http://myintranet/"
```

Comment: Not able to understand the reason to get a downvote for this ques.

Comment: May be it was down-voted because you didn't mention anything about your attempts to get the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question and specify the environment you run the code: WSH or web browser. Add the relevant tags also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement. Javascript does not provide access to ActiveX objects in any modern browser.

If you want to open a browser window, use `window.open()`.